# Integral transform of gaussian function

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-transforms

I am looking for an integral transform of $f(x)=\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})$ such that:

$$(Tf)(u)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\, K(x,u)f(x)\,dx\,\stackrel{??}{=}\,\frac{a}{g(u)}$$

with $g(u)$ having zeros depending on $\sigma$.

Anybody has a clue if that could be possible? Or any similar expression, where I have my initial $f$ transformed to a function with asymptotes depending on $\sigma$.

Thanks!

EDIT: it is also fine to have some final function that has a maximum depending on $\sigma$, instead of an asymptote.

EDIT 2: here is an example of integral transform that gives me a function with a maximum depending on $\sigma$, but it turns out to be quite broaden around the maximum. A more narrowed function is required.

$$\int_0^{\infty}\,\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,x\,\sin(ax)\,\,dx= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sigma^3a\exp\left(-\frac{a^2\sigma^2}{2}\right)$$

with a maximum at $a=1/\sigma$. (Here I am considering only $a>0$)

Comment: Maybe you have an example in mind?

Comment: @RonGordon Actually, I don't anything specific in mind. The easiest cases could be $g(u)=u-\sigma^2$ or $g(u)=(u-\sigma^2)^2$. What do you think?

Comment: @RonGordon I wish to find some $g(u)$ with asymptotes depending on $\sigma$!

Comment: @RonGordon I thought that for me is also fine to have a maximum (or more) depending on $\sigma$, not necessarily an asymptote! What do you think then?

Comment: I don't know - what you are doing seems still a bit too abstract to be able to make a judgment.  Perhaps a little background will help.

Comment: @RonGordon Ok...the problem is that I should fit data that are the weighted sum of gaussian functions. The idea behind the integral transform is to separate in a better way the contribution of the gaussians, i.e. find another space where I can more easily decouple them based on their different variances. I don't know if it is clear what I mean and if it helps some way. Thanks